# asp.mvc how do I submit mulitple forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.mvc app the presents to the user different forms when they click on the next button - like a wizard. I do it this way so I can use JQuery to validate each form as the user progresses through them. i.e.

```
   ...
   // use jquery validator to funk up the form validation
   // user clicks the Next button ...
   switch(currPageIndex) {
        case 0:
        if($('#form1'.valid()) {
            $('#form1').hide();
            $('#form2').show();
        }
        break;

   }
   ...
```

However I can't use a single submit button to post the all the forms formcollection data back to my controller - if I do I only get back the one form that the submit button was in and not all of them.

Is there some magic icantation I can type in to get all the forms data sent back to the controller?

Presumably I can cruft up the data myself and send it back to my controller as a jason string, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wizard-like forms basically rely on a model which is kept on the server-side (in session or a database table) and kept updated.

For example, each post from the client you get back the model from session or database and then call `UpdateModel()` using the FormCollection which updates the model and the you can check if it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can only submit one form at a time, however there are multiple ways around this in your scenario. When you change to the second form you could populate some hidden fields using javascript that would contain the information from the previous form. Then it would all be in the second form and you wouldn't have a problem getting the information.

You could also do it via ajax/json, but then you would probably want to do it with both of the forms data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using  `$('#form1').submit()` function, I don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just json'd up the form data and ajax'd it over to the controller, it works very well, nice and and clean to.

many thanks for the replies.

Comment: if you liked the answers, people like when you vote them up. even if you don't select it as the answer.